When can I use "the" before comparatives?

Sara is the younger (or) the youngest of her two sisters.

When can I use "the" before comparative?
And is the following correct?

Sara is younger than her two sisters


The title of this post is "What's the correct answer?"  This title does not summarise the content  I suggest you change it to something like "When can I use "the" before comparative?"

Id the first sentence is the question you want answered then the presence of "the" is irrelevant. It's about whether "younger" or "youngest" is appropriate.

If I understand you right, the first sentence is a test question you are asked, and amounts to whether it is correct or write:

Sara is the younger of her two sisters.

or

Sara is the youngest of her two sisters.

The answer is that the question is messed up and neither is correct.
"Her two sisters" does not include Sara. She is not the anything of her two sisters. She cannot be the "younger" or the "youngest" of a group of people she is not part of. It would be like saying "the giraffe is the tallest of the dogs". A giraffe is not a dog and cannot be the tallest of them.
The question could be fixed by asking:

Sara is the younger or the youngest of the two sisters in her family.

(The correct answer is "younger" because there are a total of two sisters)
or

Sara is the younger or the youngest out of her and her two sisters.

(The correct answer is "youngest" because there are a total of three sisters)
or

Sara is younger or youngest than her two sisters

(The correct answer is always "younger", whatever the number of sisters, because it is a comparative.)

Thanks. I got it. It might be a typo.

For the second question Ronald said it's correct to say 'Sara is younger than her two sisters.' Don't we use comparative to compare two persons or two things? In this sentence we compare more than two. I got confused.

@OA Consider: "John is younger/older than the other boys in his team." We are comparing John's age with that of other boys. It is not necessary to make it a one to one comparison. Another example: "That house is older than the other buildings in this area."

Yes, I got it .Many thanks

Sara is the youngest of the three sisters. She is also younger than her two (older) sisters.
You will also hear people say that he or she is "youngest" without the article "the". Ditto for "oldest" or "the oldest".
Additionally, you will come across "the younger" and "the older" without the following noun, but only after those involved have already been identified, so that the person being referred to is understood.
"Sara and Mary are sisters; Sara is younger" (than Mary). Or "Sara is the younger" (sister).

Thanks. I need to know the answer of the first question as it a multiple choice question in a grammar book. Sara is the..... of her two sisters. youngest or younger
